# Filter lists that are dictionary values

Tags: c#

```cs
Dictionary<int, List<int>> foo = GetFoo();
foreach (var (key, items) in foo)
{
    items = items.Where(item => item % 2 == 0); // unfortunately not in-place
    foo[key] = items; // unfortunately breaks iterator
}
```

I have a dictionary mapping keys to lists of ints `{ key: [ 1, 2, 3, ... ] }`

How can I filter the values of the dictionary? I want to get `{ key: [2, 4, ...] }` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveAll_System_Predicate__0__), which takes a `Predicate<T>`:

```
foreach (var items in foo.Values)
{
    items.RemoveAll(item => item % 2 == 0);
}
```

Comment: You can just use a for loop without breaking the iterator.

Comment: this answer would not be break iterator , because it remove from list , not dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all keys and set filtered list for the current key.

```
foreach (var key in foo.Keys.ToList())
{
    foo[key] = foo[key].Where(item => item % 2 == 0).ToList();
}
```